# How to pass custom typed multi-dimmensional array as a function parameter in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function

I've made a simple custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE public."FriendDetails" AS
   ("Email" character varying,
    "Name" character varying);
ALTER TYPE public."FriendDetails"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

To be used in the following function (It just returns a string - `contact!`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."addFriend"(
    "GroupName" character varying,
    friends "FriendDetails"[])
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    RETURN "contact!";
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public."addFriend"(character varying, "FriendDetails"[])
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The above code was generated using pgAdminIII.

I tried to query it as follows:

```
select addFriend('Champs',ARRAY[['qwe','asd'],['zxc','rty']]::public."FriendDetails"[]);
```

And got an error:

```
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "qwe"
LINE 1: select addFriend('Champs',ARRAY[['qwe','asd'],['zxc','rty']]...
                                         ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
********** Error **********

ERROR: malformed record literal: "qwe"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Missing left parenthesis.
Character: 34
```

I tried substituting curly braces ({}), and losing the `ARRAY`, but nothing seems to work - they'll resulted in syntax errors.

Can someone kindly show how the syntax should be to invoke this method using the (1) curly braces and (2) by using the `ARRAY` constructor.

Comment: [Composite Value Input](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rowtypes.html#AEN8006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in your code:

[Use round brackets for row/record types constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rowtypes.html#AEN8006):

```
ARRAY[('qwe','asd'),('zxc','rty')]
```

Add doublequotes to function name:

```
select "addFriend"('Champs',ARRAY[('qwe','asd'),('zxc','rty')]::public."FriendDetails"[]);
```

Use singlequotes for string constants:

```
RETURN 'contact!';
```

Comment: Thank you. This has been a real help. I also understand we can write the same without the `ARRAY` syntax. Using only the `{}`. Could you show me how?

Comment: @Vineet `select "addFriend"('Champs','{"(qwe,asd)","(zxc,rty)"}');` - the simplest way.

Comment: Thank you once again. :)

Comment: [Could you help answer this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572426/improve-formatting-of-returned-array-of-composites-too-many-escaped-characters)